# Converting annual interbank rates into monthly rates

Tags: rate-of-return

I have a time series of the three month interbank rate each month. I suppose that the rate is give annually. I need these interbank rates to be on a monthly basis because I want to us these rate as a proxy for the risk- free rate, so I can subtract the rates from my monthly return to get the excess rate. Let me make an example. Let`s say the monthly return of stock x in April is 6%. The interbank rate at the end of April is 3% annually. Can I simply subtract o.25%(3/12) from 6% resulting in 5.75% of excess return.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you're looking for is

```
Monthly rate = (1 + rate p.a.)^(1/12) – 1
```

Thus, from 3% p.a. you get ca. 0.247% per month. However, as you see 0.25% is a good approximation (generally, small rates give good approximation).

Comment: 3 Month LIBOR is quoted on annual nominal basis. 3% (nominal) annually means 3/12 x 3% = 0.75% (effective) for 3 months. Then you can use Monthly rate = (1 + 0.75%)^(1/3) – 1 = 0.2494%

Comment: I'm not sure that interbank rate is automatically 3m-LIBOR in any country and any exchange (e.g. what is LIBOR for Indian rupee?). However, it's still a good idea to precise how the interbank rate is compounded